# React custom axios hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I have built a custom Axios hook to handle requests and would like to add the `AbortController` to cancel requests to prevent this error from happening.

[image]

However in my custom hook, I don't have a useEffect to clean up the code, where should I run the `controller.abort()`.

My custom hook:

```js
const useAxios = () => {
  const { setModal } = useContext(ModalContext);

  return (url, method = "get", data = {}) => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    return instance({ method, url, data, signal: controller.signal }).catch(
      (error) => {
        setModal(() => (
          <div>
            <h1>{error.message}</h1>
          </div>
        ));
        throw error;
      }
    );
  };
};
```

Comment: Did you try run `controller.abort()` in clean up function of `useEffect`?

Comment: I don't use a `useEffect` in the function

Comment: @MJA This issue doesn't refer to the effect itself but indicates that you're trying to change the state of the unmounted component. You should use useEffect to handle the request.

Comment: If I try to do this, I will not be able to use the custom hook inside another useEffect to fetch data on render because I will be getting this error: React Hook "useFetch" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.eslintreact-hooks/rules-of-hooks